# Conditional expected waiting time for a bus to arrive given number of people waiting

Tags: statistics

Suppose there are $N$ people and each person arrives at the bus stop after a waiting time distributed i.i.d. as an exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$. Suppose further that the bus arrives after an amount of time distributed as a truncated normal distribution with original mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$ before truncation, where the truncation is to enforce non-negativity of the waiting time for the bus. Given that there are $k$ people currently waiting at the bus stop, what is the expected amount of time remaining until the bus arrives? This is not homework, I'm basically wondering if there is a closed form solution or whether an ugly integral has to be evaluated numerically.

Comment: "Truncated" to which interval (a,b)?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by truncation?

Comment: Sorry I meant truncated to be non-negative. I'll clarify the problem statement.